# Show that if $A \subset B$ then $\sigma(A) \subset \sigma$ (B)

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory

Hello I am trying to show that for subsets $A,B \in \Omega$ with $A \subset B$ then $\sigma(A) \subset \sigma(B).$ The textbook I am studying is Probability and Measure Theory Second Edition by Robert B. Ash and the definition given in the book for a $\sigma$ field of a collection of subsets $A \in \Omega$ is such that $\sigma(A)$ is closed under complementation and countable union i.e.:

$\sigma(A)$ satisfies these properties:

1. $\Omega \in \sigma (A).$
2. If any subset $X \in \sigma(A)$ then $X^c \in \sigma(A).$
3. If $X_1, X_2,  X_3, \ldots, \in \sigma (A)$ then $\left( \bigcup \limits_{i=1}^\infty X_i \right) \in \sigma(A).$

Based on this definition, to me it would seem rather obvious that A $\subset$ B would imply $\sigma(A) \subset \sigma(B)$ since the $\sigma$ field of a collection of sets that belong in the domain $\Omega$ expands the original collection of sets to include all possible combinations of the complements and unions of the original elements in the collection of sets so the assumption of $A \subset B$ would imply all the elements of $A$ are in $B$ so taking the $\sigma$ field of $B$ is really taking the $\sigma$ field of $A$ and then adding to it the $\sigma$ field of $(A - B)$ or $A \cap B^c$ i.e. $\sigma(B) = \sigma(A) + \sigma(A - B) = \sigma(A) \cup \sigma(A - B).$ To me this proof seems reasonable enough to lead to the result of $\sigma(A) \subset \sigma(B)$ but I just wanted to make sure if my argument is reasonable enough to lead to this conclusion or if there is anything else that can be added to strengthen it.

Comment: Your definition needs to include $A\in \sigma(A).$ (As it stands, it has no dependence on $A$ at all.) And after that you need to include the fact that it's the smallest set with these closure properties (i.e. the intersection of all sets with these properties).

Comment: You said $A,B\in\Omega,$ but in order that this make sense, it seems to me that you would want $A,B$ to be families of subsets of $\Omega.$ Also, note my edits for proper MathJax usage.

Comment: Ahh yes, Michael Hardy is right. Your definition needs to include $A\subseteq \sigma(A),$ not $A\in \sigma(A),$ and you want $A,B\subseteq \mathcal P(\Omega),$ not $A,B\in \Omega.$

Comment: If $A$ and $B$ are just two subsets of $\Omega$ this is obviously false. What exactly is the meaning of $A,B \in \Omega$?.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You've got the right idea, but you could be a bit more detailed by noting that $\sigma(A)$ is the **smallest** $\sigma$-algebra containing $A$ (i.e., it's the intersection of all $\sigma$-algebras containing $A$).

If $A \subseteq B$, then any $\sigma$-algebra ${\cal F}$ containing $B$ will also contain $A$.   Thus, the intersection of all $\sigma$-algebras containing $A$ must be a subset of the intersection of all $\sigma$-algebras containing $B$.  If $B$ is much larger than $A$, the reverse inclusion need not hold.

Comment: Thank you for pointing this out, so a more reasonable argument would basically be that A $\subset$ B implies that A $\in$ $\sigma$ (B) with $\sigma$ (B) being the smallest intersection of the $\sigma$-algebras containing B which automatically also contains the small intersection of all the $\sigma$ algebras of A?

Comment: @Jmath99 $\mathcal A\subseteq\mathcal B$ implies that $\mathcal A\subseteq\sigma(\mathcal B)$ (not $\in$ here). No, the point is that $\sigma(\mathcal A)$ is the intersection of all $\sigma$-fields that contain $\mathcal A$ as a subcollection and that $\sigma(B)$ is one of these $\sigma$-fields. That implies $\sigma(\mathcal A)\subseteq\sigma(\mathcal B)$.

Comment: Close, but take a look at Michael Hardy and spaceisgreen's comments on your original question.  I assumed you meant that $A$ and $B$ are families of subsets of $\Omega$, not elements of $\Omega$ itself.  You need to be a bit more careful distinguishing which sets are subsets of each other, which are collections of subsets of another (and therefore, subsets of a power set), etc.

In general, your question has little to do with $\sigma$-algebras and is really amounts to the following set theoretic fact:  If $\emptyset \subset S \subseteq T$, then $\bigcap T \subseteq \bigcap S$.

Answer (score 3):

> "...expands the original collection of sets to include all possible combinations of the complements and unions of the original elements in the collection of sets..."

That is a weak point, since it will only be acceptable as mathematical proof if you define *exactly* what you mean with "all possible combinations of the complements and unions" and secondly prove that $\sigma(\mathcal A)$ falls together with it.

To prove it correctly it must be shown that an intersection of $\sigma$-fields is again a $\sigma$-field. If that is done (and it is not really difficult) then it can be concluded that $\sigma(\mathcal A)$ is the intersection of all $\sigma$-fields on $\Omega$ that contain $\mathcal A$.

Then from $\mathcal A\subseteq\mathcal B\subseteq\sigma(\mathcal B)$ it follows that $\sigma(\mathcal B)$ is one of these $\sigma$-fields that contain $\mathcal A$ as subcollection, so that $\sigma(\mathcal B)$ is automatically a superset of that intersection of $\sigma$-fields.