# Does $A\subset B \not \Rightarrow \sigma(A)\subset \sigma(B)$?

Tags: measure-theory

First sorry for the provocative question as we know that $A\subset B \Rightarrow \sigma(A)\subset \sigma(B)$ and I understood the [proof](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2909071/736212).

I tried to think on a simple example to wrap my head around it so I thought about:

$A=\{1,2\}, B=\{1,2,3\}, X=\{1,2,3,4\}$

So $\sigma(B)=\{\emptyset,X,\{1,2,3\},\{4\}\}$ or is it $\sigma(B)=\{\emptyset,X,1,2,3,4\}$?

Comment: The statement in the link is about sets $A$ and $B$ of subsets of $X$. Their elements are subsets of $X$. In your example $A$ and $B$ are subsets of $X$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We use notation $\sigma(\mathcal B)$ if $\mathcal B\subseteq\wp(X)$, i.e. $\mathcal B$ is a collection of subsets of universal set $X$ (so not a subset of $X$).

In that context: $$\sigma(\{\{1,2,3\}\})=\{\emptyset,X,\{1,2,3\},\{4\}\}$$

Characteristic for $\sigma(\mathcal A)$ is that it is a $\sigma$-algebra that contains $\mathcal A$ and moreover is a subcollection of every $\sigma$-algebra that contains $\mathcal A$.

If $\mathcal A\subseteq\mathcal B$ then $\sigma(\mathcal B)$ is a $\sigma$-algebra that contains $\mathcal A$, hence $\sigma(\mathcal A)\subseteq\sigma(\mathcal B)$.

Comment: So $A=\{\{1\}\}$ and $B=\{\{1\},\{2\}\}$ and $X=\{1,2,3\}$ is a good example?

Comment: Sure. I would not write $A,B$ but $\mathcal A$ (i.e. \mathcal A) and $\mathcal B$ to emphasize that we are dealing with collections of subsets of $X$ (and not subsets).

Answer (score 2):

I'm afraid you're a bit confused. For $\sigma(A)$ to be defined, you need $A$ to be a subset of the power-set of $X$. In your case, $$\sigma(\{A\})=\{\emptyset,X,\{1,2\},\{2,4\}\} \\ \sigma(\{B\})=\{\emptyset,X,\{1,2,3\},\{4\}\},$$ 
which clearly are non-comparable. The correct statement would be that $\sigma(\{A\})\subseteq \sigma(\{A,B\})$.